# How to expand/collapse attributions programmatically?

Tags: javascript, legend, openlayers-3, expand

I added an attribution as legend,and it can be expanded or collapsed manually,but how to do it programmatically?

Comment: Time to give a feedback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `setCollapsible` & `setCollapsed` methods on `ol.control.Attribution`:

See http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/attributions.html & http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.control.Attribution.html#setCollapsed

Answer (score 0):

Find the button and fire a click on it.

```
var fireClick = function(node) {
  if (typeof MouseEvent === 'function') {
    var mevt = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: win,
      bubbles: false,
      cancelable: true
    });
    node.dispatchEvent(mevt);
  } else if ( doc.createEvent ) {
    // Fallback
    var evt = doc.createEvent('MouseEvents');
    evt.initEvent('click', false, false);
    node.dispatchEvent(evt);
  } else if (doc.createEventObject) {
    node.fireEvent('onclick') ;
  } else if (typeof node.onclick === 'function' ) {
    node.onclick();
  }
};

var map_element = document.getElementById('map');
var button = map_element.querySelector('div.ol-attribution button');

fireClick(button);
```

Comment: Wouldn't do it that way when there are API method available…

Comment: @tonio Ohh well ... for sure. I didn't think of it.